# Null Pointer Exception when Compressing a Bitmap created from layout

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am trying to make an image from the layout and download it.  I am downloading this as a test to make sure the image is correct before I attempt to then convert the bitmap to PDF for download.

I am receiving a null pointer exception, and I am having issues trying to fix this issue.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(relativeLayout.getWidth(), relativeLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                relativeLayout.draw(canvas);

                File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Demo/");
                dir.mkdir();
                File file = new File(dir, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

                try {
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, outputStream);

                try {
                    outputStream.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 File file = new File(dir, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
```

You declared `File` here, but did not create it

try `file.createNewFile()`

Comment: Why did you close this? I've read the above but it doesn't make sense. I'm new to the community and this seems very harsh. I'm just trying to figure out how to make something work and you shut me down?